# Python tronpy -- account not found on-chain (get_account_balance())

Tags: python, cryptoapi, tron, tronpy

have a exceptions when try to get a acount balance use a tronpy
exception: tronpy.exceptions.AddressNotFound: account not found on-chain

have this problem with a new wallet and with a just adress from tronscan

code to create account

```
tron = Tron()

def create_wallet(): 
    wallet = tron.generate_address()
    
    return wallet
```

code to get account balance

```
def get_balance(address):
    balance = tron.get_account_balance(address)
    
    return balance

balance = get_balance(wallet['base58check_address'])
print("Balance:", balance)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this simply means that the address is not activated.

Comment: Did uou fix this problem?